# Turning off Windows Update on Google Cloud Platform Windows Virtual Machine (Server 2016)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

Much as it pains me to do so, I have to run a Windows VM on Google Cloud Platform in order to run some legacy data extraction software on a nightly basis.

It works fine (except the recurring feeling that I am stepping back in time every time I RDP into the VM), except over the holidays when the extract stopped.  I checked the update logs and it seemed to be when an automatic Windows Update took place.  As such I want to stop these from happening, however I cannot find any way of stopping them!

I own the GCP project and VM, so should have permissions to change any settings I like, does anybody have a clue how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

You do have the right to do whatever in your VM Windows.

**For windows 7**

> 1- Log in to the Windows 7 or Windows 8 guest operating system as an
>   administrator.
>
> 2- Click Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Turn automatic
>   updating on or off.
>
> 3- In the Important updates menu, select Never check for updates.
>
> 4- Deselect Give me recommended updates the same way I receive
>   important updates.
>
> 5- Deselect Allow all users to install updates on this computer and
>   click OK.

**For Windows 10**

I suugest your to follow the steps provided [Here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/08/26/windows-10-how-to-stop-forced-updates/#4c6d1cb046f6) as the windows 10 has a policy of [forced updates](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/07/17/windows-10-forced-automatic-updates/) three option available.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alioua, unfortunately I am running Windows Server 2016 so it looked like I was in the same situation as Windows 10 (i.e. no option to disbale auto-updates).  However I did manage to track this down for Server 2016 and it seems to work: https://community.shavlik.com/docs/DOC-24588

Answer (score 0):

Tracked down the answer!  Posting here in case it helps somebody else...

https://community.shavlik.com/docs/DOC-24588

Solution

Open SCONFIG and verify your current Windows Update Settings:

Open a command prompt with Admin permissions.
Type sconfig and press Enter.
NOTE: There may be a short pause as the tool inspects your system.
Option #5 shows the current configuration of your Windows Update settings.
Config.PNG

To change your Automatic Update Settings, follow these steps:

From the SCONFIG screen press 5 and then Enter. This will bring up the following options for you to choose from:

(A)utomatic – This will configure your machine to automatically scan, download, install and reboot after applying any updates.
(D)ownloadOnly – This will automatically scan, download and notify the admin if updates need to be installed. This is the default setting on Windows Server 2016.
(M)anual -- This turns Automatic Updates off. Your system will never check for updates.

```
2. Press the letter specified in the "( )" and press Enter to apply.

3. When the tool applies the configuration you have selected, you will see a message pop-up similar to the one below. Click the OK button to dismiss the message. The tool will refresh the menu and option 5 will now show the new configuration.
```